How do I apply processes on multiple rasters in GRASS GIS?
Im new in GRASS GIS and I want to use multiple Sentinel-2 L2A scenes to do a time series analysis on a flood incident. I imported my data with i.sentinel.import, which imports the Bands that I want (B03, B11) and it also imports the respective cloud mask for each scene as a vector. I want to preprocess multiple scenes by resampling the 20m Bands to 10m and I want to apply multiple cloud masks.
Now, using the r.resample module I can only resample one image at a time and regarding the r.mask module it applies a mask for all my scenes not only for the corresponding one.
The ultimate question is how do I "automate" the process so that I have all bands on 10m resolution and each scene masked with the corresponding cloud mask?
